# Can't find GDB option in Eclipse on mac

Tags: eclipse, debugging, go, gdb, preferences

I'm new to Macs but I don't think this is a problem that comes from that. I've been attempting to set up GDB as a debugger for programming in golang on Eclipse. I know how to do it for the most part, but at some point one of the steps is to open up your debug preferences in the C/C++ configuration and fill in the path of where the debugger is located. Unfortunately, the option doesn't even show up for me:
[image]

Why doesn't the "GDB" option show up under Preferences >> C/C++ >> Debug? If i'm not mistaken, it should be a part of the CDT package correct? Am I just using the wrong version? It should be giving me this option:

[image]

At least it does for Neil Craft, the author of [this tutorial](http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/)

Comment: I suggest using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [vscode-go](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go) plugin, doesn't answer your question but just a suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone coming here looking for an answer:
https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/macmingweclipse/allexperimental/mac-gdb-install.html#eclipse

> If there is no GDB section in the C/C++Debug subtree, close the preferences window, and try to first start a debugging session for any project that you can already run without problems. You can do it by either clicking the Debug button on the toolbar, or selecting RunDebug from the main menu. This attempt will, of course, fail with an error message about the gdb command, but it will force the said C/C++DebugGDB settings to appear in the preferences.